# Meaning of the symbol '<>'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to know the meaning of `<>` in Python. In Visual Basic, it means that if we have `a<>0` then `a` is not equal to zero.

Comment: That is not valid python3 syntax.

Comment: If the question is "how to do `<>` in python", the answer is `!=`

Comment: i found it in this code 
def jacobi(a, m):
    # assumes a an integer and
    # m an odd positive integer
    a, t = a % m, 1
    while a <> 0:
        z = -1 if m % 8 in [3,5] else 1
        while a % 2 == 0:
            a, t = a / 2, t * z
        if a%4 == 3 and m%4 == 3: t = -t
        a, m = m % a, a
    return t if m == 1 else 0
    
print jacobi(3,17)

Comment: That code isn't Python 3.

Comment: It's a valid Python 2 comparison operator, see [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) in the online docs. Support for it was removed in Python 3 (`!=` was always preferred).

Answer (score 8):

It's the same in Python 2, it means "not equal". See [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`.

Python 3 does not have the `<>` operator.

Comment: Only in python 2, not python 3.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Thanks, added it to the answer

Comment: thank you all i catch the idea